# HTML table code creates unaligned table

Tags: html, email, html-email, mailchimp

I'm trying to align my photos and their descriptions in this table but have no clue what I'm missing. I'd like the images/descriptions to all be touching and connected if possible.

Here is my code, pretty simple email template in HTML for mailchimp:

```html
<body background="http://i.imgur.com/M0jxU8g.jpg"><table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="http://themilamgroup.com/email/templates/fallinventory/images/promo/promo_3_large.jpg" height="175px" width="300px"></td>
<td><div style="background-color:#142232; height:135px;width:280px; color:#ffffff; padding:20px; text-align:center;">PENDED<br>
$775,000
<br><br>
1771 Charity Drive<br>
Brentwood, TN 37027
<br><br>
4 bdrm, 3.5 ba, 4115 sq ft</div></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
   <td>
    <div style="background-color:#142232; height:135px;width:280px;color:#ffffff; text-align:center; padding:20px">PENDED<br>
$775,000
<br><br>
1771 Charity Drive<br>
Brentwood, TN 37027
<br><br>
4 bdrm, 3.5 ba, 4115 sq ft</div></td>
   <td><img src="http://themilamgroup.com/email/templates/fallinventory/images/promo/promo_3_large.jpg" height="175px" width="300px"></td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td><img src="http://themilamgroup.com/email/templates/fallinventory/images/promo/promo_3_large.jpg" height="175px" width="300px"></td>
<td>
    <div style="background-color:#142232; height:135px;width:280px;color:#ffffff; text-align:center; padding:20px">PENDED<br>
$775,000
<br><br>
1771 Charity Drive<br>
Brentwood, TN 37027
<br><br>
4 bdrm, 3.5 ba, 4115 sq ft</div></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
   <td>
    <div style="background-color:#142232; height:135px;width:280px;color:#ffffff; text-align:center; padding:20px">PENDED<br>
$775,000
<br><br>
1771 Charity Drive<br>
Brentwood, TN 37027
<br><br>
4 bdrm, 3.5 ba, 4115 sq ft</div></td>
  </tr>
</table></body>
```

What it looks like:
[image]

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6j5jLccj/1/) what you need?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a table, the only way you will achieve this is if the content of every cell in the column is the same width.  Otherwise, the width of the column will always be defined by the cell with the widest content.

You could float the content in the left hand column to the right, which would achieve what you are after, but I wouldn't consider that a desirable solution personally.  It will look much neater if you size all your content to be the same width.

At the moment your information DIVs are 320px wide - a width of 280px, plus 20px padding on both sides.  Changing the padding to just 10px on the sides will make all your content 300px wide.

You could then add the following attributes to your table tag if you want zero spacing:

```
cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you zero out the `<table>`'s default value and inline `display:block;` for each image, that should negate all the unintended space in your preview above.

```
<table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- text goes here -->
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="" alt="" style="display: block;">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```